# Community Error

Tags: community

I have a community that I can no longer access.  I am getting the message "Error:__MISSING LABEL_PropertyFile - val SiteLoginFailureEcxeption not found in Section Exception.  When I look at it in Communities setup via Lightning, it does not show that I can login to it to make any changes, etc.  [image]

Comment: I realize that I removed the System Admin profile from the community.  I have found online instructions on how to use Data Loader to readd the profile to the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instructions for adding the system administrator profile as a member of a community - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=How-do-I-add-myself-as-a-member-of-a-Community-if-the-Manage-Link-is-missing&language=en_US&type=1